# Keeping indexes of an elements in the array after sorting in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I want that sorting array without actually changing its data. So I want only keep its indexes in another array. For this I use Bubble Sort algorithm, and at every swapping step I change elements of new array which keeps indexes of actual array. That's my code, but it doesn't work correctly

```
int[] bSort(int[] arrivalTimes) {
    int[] sequence = new int[arrivalTimes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        sequence[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrivalTimes.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrivalTimes.length; j++) {
            if (arrivalTimes[i] > arrivalTimes[j]) {
                int temp = sequence[i];
                sequence[i] = sequence[j];
                sequence[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

So if input array is [2, 5, 1, 0, 4]

Then sequence array should be [3, 2, 0, 4, 1] (indexes of actual array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to sort the actual array also. If the arrivalTimes array isn't sorted, your condition will not act the way you expect.

```
int[] bSort(int[] arrivalTimes) {
    int[] sequence = new int[arrivalTimes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        sequence[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrivalTimes.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrivalTimes.length; j++) {
            if (arrivalTimes[i] > arrivalTimes[j]) {
                int temp = sequence[i];
                sequence[i] = sequence[j];
                sequence[j] = temp;
                
                int temp2 = arrivalTimes[i];
                arrivalTimes[i] = arrivalTimes[j];
                arrivalTimes[j] = temp2;               
            }
        }
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

This is an inefficient solution though. I suspect this is part of some algorithms assignment so I'll leave the optimisations up to you.

Comment: Can I use merge sort for this problem?

Comment: Take some time to think about various ways you can achieve the end goal. You could create an array of pairs<int,int> with the <value,index> then sort by value, which would provide the indices in the desired order. You could also use a map to hash the key, value pairs, use an nlogn sort then query the map. You could use an ordered map.. etc etc... it's up to you to decide which approach best serves your needs. There are lots of data structures that you can use for this problem. I think the best solution will not require too much memory overhead though so keep that in mind.